# How to flush out the Shared function data from CPU cache

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-cache

I am creating a shared data for two processes and then after reading data from CPU cache, I want to flush out the shared function data from CPU cache. I am able to find the starting address of that particular shared data 
in cache memory but unable to find the last address.

I can flush any address using clflush(address) from CPU cache. but the challenge is how to flush the function , and I only know the starting address of function.

Is there any way to find the last address of that shared data/function in CPU cache? I am using GCC under Linux.

Comment: I think that's more a responsibility of the MMU (hardware) than the OS itself.

Comment: @PauloBu - thanks.Actually,there is something rule or formula by which OS or MMU , choosing a particular location in cache memory for storing the data from physical address.I want to know that rule so that I can understand the internal architecture.

Comment: Ok, as far as I know, OS make certain alinements to some data structures to keep them inside the cache but I don't know any more deeper than that. Let's hope someone answer :)

Comment: You should not care about that (inside application code). Trust the kernel about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "cache memory"? Are you talking about the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)?

Comment: I suspect you are referring to physical memory and linux OS cache memory?   not the hardware cache right?   Linux OS cache is per-structures, and so different objects in Linux kernel have different caches involved.   It is just located in the physical memory somewhere, never paged out from the kernel.   Not really sure what is the mapping you are looking for?

Comment: @sleske - It is CPU cache memory (L1, L2 and L3 cache).

Comment: @Amit_T: Ok, that makes things clearer. Now, *why* are you asking about the relationship? Do you have a specific problem? What do you want to do with the information?

Comment: @sleske - Actually,I am creating a shared data between two process and now I want to flush out the shared data from CPU cache memory and that's why I want to know the starting address and last address of that shared data in the CPU cache memory. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You didn't specify your machine, but your CPU caches are most likely mapped already by physical address, why do you need a mapping?

Comment: @Amit_T: That does not make sense. Why do you want to "flush out the shared data from CPU cache memory"? What does that even mean? The CPU cache is usually fully transparent for software, so you don't need to (and usually cannot) flush it.

Comment: @Leeor - I am using GCC under Linux.I agree CPU caches are already mapped by physical address but my question is How this mapping done?Is there any rule or formula by which physical address is pointing any particular location in CPU cache memory?

Comment: @sleske - i can flush out any particular memory location in CPU cache memory by using clflush(address) and some how I am able to find the starting address of that particular shared data in CPU cache memory but I am not able to find the last address of that particular shared data in CPU cache memory.

Comment: `Is there any rule or formula by which physical address is pointing any particular location in CPU cache memory` - of course, cache set is determined by a subset of the address bits (if a cache line is 64 Byte, then bits 0..5 are for the byte within the line, and 6 and above is for the set selection), unless there's some set-shuffling trick (pretty rare). The number of set bits is determined by the cache size and associativity.

Comment: @Amit_T: Sorry, can't really help. I know very little about assembly and CPU caches. Try editing your question to describe the actual problem you face. Otherwise this question will probably be closed as too unclear.